# Windows 7 unattended installation using PXE

Tags: windows-7, installation, pxe, unattended, winpe

I have followed this [blog](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-pxe-server-to-install-windows-on-centos/) and I am able to install Windows 7 over a PXE Server and Samba shares.

But this installation process is not completely automated. It boots the system using **WinPE** image created using **Windows Automated Installation Kit**. After WinPE image finishes loading, it shows a command prompt window on screen. Then I am mapping Windows installation sources configured on PXE Samba share directory, as a Network drive(*net use z: \192.168.1.20\install\x64*) and running *setup.exe* utility to start windows installation.

Is there any way to avoid this step and start windows installation directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should run a script directly from WinPE automatically once it boots.

This script should map the drive, execute the startup and do any other functions you require.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/85579/windows-pe-autorun-scripts) seems to explain best how to do this:

> Under the "sources" folder on the PE key is the "boot.wim" file.
>
> Mount Boot WIM: dism /Mount-Wim /wimfile:C:[WPE PATH]\sources\boot.wim
>   /index:1 /MountDir:C:\Mounted_images\boot
>
> Then the file can be found at:
>   C:\Mounted_images\boot\Windows\System32\startnet.cmd
>
> Commit changes and Unmount WIM: dism /Unmount-Wim
>   /MountDir:C:\Mounted_images\boot /commit
>
> If you want to discard changes instead: dism /Unmount-Wim
>   /MountDir:C:\Mounted_images\boot /discard